# Central Path to store Pandoc Writer

Tags: pandoc

I have written [a custom writer for pandoc](https://pandoc.org/custom-writers.html) in `lua`, say `mywriter.lua`.

Is there a central path I can store it in my machine, so that I can invoke `pandoc` with [`-t mywriter.lua`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#custom-readers-and-writers) in order to use my custom writer, regardless from the directory I run this command?

For templates, I know I can use `usr/share/pandoc/data/templates`, as pandoc will look for templates in that directory if it could not resolve the reference to a template locally. Is there something similar for custom writers?

I have looked through the documentation and searched the internet, but I didn't find an answer.
I also tried to guess a path. The following paths did *not* work:

- `/usr/share/pandoc/mywriter.lua`
- `/usr/share/pandoc/data/mywriter.lua`
- `/usr/share/pandoc/data/templates/mywriter.lua`
- `~/.pandoc/mywriter.lua`
- `~/.pandoc/templates/mywriter.lua`
- `~/.local/share/pandoc/mywriter.lua`
- `~/.local/share/pandoc/filters/mywriter.lua`
- `~/.local/share/pandoc/defaults/mywriter.lua`

If this is relevant, I work on an Ubuntu machine.

Answer (score 2):

It seems there is no way in Pandoc version (2.18) . After lots of investigations (and completing your list of dead-ends) I opened a Pandoc [issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8135)

**Update**: For Pandoc version 2.19+ the location is ["data directory"](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--data-dir)`/writers`. Meaning `~/.local/share/pandoc/writers/` on Linux and macOS.

For Pandoc version 3+, the [new location](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/8203#issuecomment-1546666823) is ["data directory"](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#option--data-dir)`/custom`. Meaning, on macOS, you would put the writer in `~/.local/share/pandoc/custom/mywriter.lua`.

Comment: Thanks! Might be worth mentioning that I already asked about this on the pandoc mailing list (pandoc-discuss) - https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/Tk1SDZQ4DaA/m/v1OH6XwmCAAJ They suggested to use a different path, but you tried this already, didn't you?

Comment: Incidentally, we added support for this just a couple of days ago: <https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/pull/8112>. There isn't a new release yet, but you can use the latest nightly build.